# LinearGradientBrush not applied correctly to TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, gradient

Here is the script :

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

TextBlock t = new TextBlock();
t.Text = "a very very very very very very long test";
t.FontSize = 28;
t.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
t.Width = 500;
Canvas.SetLeft(t, 100);
Canvas.SetTop(t, 100);

Line l = new Line();
l.X1 = 100;
l.Y1 = 100;
l.X2 = 200;
l.Y2 = 100;
l.StrokeThickness = 2.0;

LinearGradientBrush b = new LinearGradientBrush(Colors.Red, Colors.Black, 0);
b.MappingMode = BrushMappingMode.Absolute;
b.StartPoint = new Point(100, 0);
b.EndPoint = new Point(200, 0);

l.Stroke = b;
t.Foreground = b;

canvas.Children.Add(l);
canvas.Children.Add(t);
```

And here is the result I get :

[image]

I really don't understand why the gradient does not behave the same on the line and on the textblock since the mappingmode is set to absolute.

**EDIT :**

Here is the result with `b.SpreadMethod = GradientSpreadMethod.Repeat;` :

[image]

In this case, the gradient seems to behave correctly (but in my case I still need to use a not-repeated gradient).

Comment: looks the same to me

Comment: Not quite, the length of the gradient applied to the line or the text is not the same on the first image. But the StartPoint and EndPoint have absolute coordinates, so the lenght of the gradient should be the same in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're misunderstanding `LinearGradientBrush.EndPoint`

See the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush.endpoint(v=vs.110).aspx)

You're trying to use `EndPoint` as where the gradient should end, respective to the form, but `EndPoint` is more like where the gradient starts changing color.

As you can see in your image, the proportion of red and black in each object is the same, not the absolute position of the transition.

Comment: The description of the EndPoint property in your link is : "The ending two-dimensional coordinates of the linear gradient". This seems to clearly express that the EndPoint is the first point where the combination of the StartColor and the EndColor is (0%, 100%). Even more strangely, when I put the SpreadMethod to Repeat, the problem seems to be gone (I'll update the first post to show the difference).